# Azure Machine learning: error with multiclass classification algo

Tags: machine-learning, azure-machine-learning-service

I have [training set](https://yadi.sk/i/--Vkm7FTkTAxY) and [test set](https://yadi.sk/i/wYu0ZsmukTAw3) (csv files with header), in which I have to classify each value. There is 118.000 uniq values in X column, and only about 13000 in y1 column, so there will be 13000 categories.

[image]

From Training set I need only `X` and `y1` column to train model. I need to classify X value to one of categories (find normal from of initial word). I tried all multi algo but failed trying to evaluate model.

Visualizing Score model return this:

[image]

What can be a problem, it just returns -2 code as error and this [log](https://yadi.sk/i/I6WiEoCGkTCXc)

UPD1: By Metadata Editor module under Project Column Module made column y1  as categorical,  nothing seems to be changed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Moncef** provided [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/azure/en-US/aabb9080-adf8-4fc0-b332-2a3c8ee29a28/azure-machine-learning-error-with-multiclass-classification-algo?forum=MachineLearning) the solution to my problem:

The point is that Azure has limitations on maximum categories 8192, this is why the number should be decreased by R or python modules or own evaluation module may be created. Or there is another way, evaluation step may be skipped, because model`ve been trained successfully.